# Condition of distinct eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I am looking at this wikipedia page

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Eigendecomposition

```
Eigendecomposition
Also called spectral decomposition
Applicable to: square matrix A with distinct eigenvectors (not necessarily distinct eigenvalues).
```

What is the conditions of having distinct eigenvectors? Is it possible to have different eigenvectors while having the same eigenvalues?

Comment: What kind of conditions are you looking for? What type of information do you have available to you that one may use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the conditions you have available to you, that you have information about.

(Sufficent)You can compute the characteristic polynomial $Det ( A- \lambda I) $ and check there are different eigenvalues, i.e., no n-ple roots for $n \times n$ matrix.

You can also just compute the eigenspaces if you have a repeated root; the eigenspaces associated to different eigenvalues are linearly independent, i.e., the basis vectors are independent of each other.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. The wikipedia page says "(not necessarily distinct eigenvalues)". I wonder is it possible to have different eigenvectors for the same eigenvalues.

Comment: @CodeNoob: Yes, it is possible, i.e., a given eigenvalue may be associated with more than one eigenvector, but I cant think of any nice condition to tell when/if this happens. This has to see with algebraic vs geometric multiplicity of eigenvectorshttp://www.cuil.pt/r.php?cx=002825717068136152164%3Aqf0jmwd8jku&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=algebraic+and+geometric+multiplicity&sa=Search .

Comment: @CodeNoob: Take the identity matrix. The whole space is the eigenspace to the eigenvalue $1$. Any basis of the space is a basis of eigenvectors. To get the reverse situation, take the companion matrix for the polynomial $(x-1)^n$. $1$ is again the only eigenvalue, the eigenspace however has only dimension $1$.

Comment: @LutzL , we are looking for general conditions under which geometric multiplicity is larger than algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: Well, it happens when the geometric multiplicity is larger than the algebraic multiplicity. This is already the best formulation. An equivalent formulation would deal with the multiplicities of irreducible factors of the minimal and the characteristic polynomial.